# How to make hbars in subplots with shared properties and no delimiter?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, subplot

My input is a dataframe `df` (you can find a snippet in the end of my question) and I try to create a plot like the second 'Panel vendor bar chart' here : https://peltiertech.com/stacked-bar-chart-alternatives

The code I made is this (by the way I'm open to any suggestations to improve it) :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('my_folder/list_of_softwares.xlsx')

sums = df.groupby('Software').sum().T

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(sums.index), sharey=True, figsize=(12, 3))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)

colors = ['#6caddf', '#f27077', '#9dd374', '#fab26a']
          
for ax, software, parameter, color in zip(axes, sums.columns, sums.index, colors):
    ax.barh(sums.loc[parameter].index, sums.loc[parameter].values, color=color)
    ax.set(xticks=range(0, df.drop('Software', axis=1).max().max()+1, 2000), title=parameter)

fig.suptitle('Summary of Softwares', y=1.05, fontweight='bold')

plt.show()
```

It works except 4 small issues :

1. The `y` ticks in all axes should be removed
2. The subtitles of the axes should be inside the figure and not outside it
3. Some `x` ticks labels are overlapping
4. The vertical line that separate each ax should be removed

I feel like this can be done easily but I don't know how.

Any ideas, guys ?

[image]

`df` look like this :

```
   Software  Parameters  Reports  Dashbords  Scorecards
0   Tableau        7935       68        474         712
1   Tableau          69      518        695         122
2    Oracle         651      540        842         764
3    Oracle         700       52        776         948
4    Oracle         758      862        182         757
5       IBM         999      271        847         338
6       IBM         316      128        395         441
7       IBM         915      199       1000         747
8       IBM          44      685        818         427
9     Tibco         500      575        876         450
10    Board         748      936        367         771
11    Board         304      700        856          77
12    Board         623      974        120         802
13    Board         131      151        395         410
14    Board         217      645        996         537
15  LogiXML         630      779        752         433
16  LogiXML         947      391        280         109
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to adjust some simple individual settings of the `ax` object, which is each individual plot:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_clipboard() # copy data in the SO question
sums = df.groupby('Software').sum().T

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(sums.index), sharey=True, figsize=(12, 3))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.2)

colors = ['#6caddf', '#f27077', '#9dd374', '#fab26a']
          
for ax, software, parameter, color in zip(axes, sums.columns, sums.index, colors):
    ax.barh(sums.loc[parameter].index, sums.loc[parameter].values, color=color)
    ax.set(xticks=range(0, df.drop('Software', axis=1).max().max()+1, 2000), )
    ax.set_title(parameter, y=0.9)
    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(length=0)
    for d in ["top", "bottom", "right", "left"]:
        ax.spines[d].set_visible(False)
    
    
fig.suptitle('Summary of Softwares', y=1.05, fontweight='bold')

plt.show()
```

[image: final_ouput]

Comment: Thank you for your time @jjsantoso but this fix only 2 and 3. We still need to fix 1 (remove only y ticks and keep y ticks labels) and 4 (remove the vertical line that separate each ax).

Comment: I edited the answer to correct ticks and remove left spine.